# Import from CSV shows less records in MySQL

Tags: mysql, csv

I am trying to import the csv in MySQL as below,

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  
'A:/PATH/travelport_new/hotel_id2.csv'
INTO TABLE giata_travelport  
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

which has `140613` records in the CSV and it got successfully imported with no errors but then it shows the total records as `140466`instead of `140613`.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `giata_travelport` (
  `hotel_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

CSV file has one column data for hotel_id(140613 records), which is getting imported but the total records count says 140466.

Comment: Could you please add more details (giata_travelport  schema, maybe there are some duplicates in csv, other...) ?

Comment: @YaroslavBaymak I just have one field in the table for now. please check the Edit